# Jquery mobile Swipe on a Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the jQuery mobile library. I want to use the swipe event on an image to swipe them with the touch of my finger on my iPhone, but it's not working. I tried to use it like this:

```
function myEvent() {
  if ($("#myImageFront").swiperight) {
    console.log("hey");
    $.mobile.changePage("localhost/myOtherPage.php")
  }
}

<img class="myImage" id="myImageFront" src="myImage.png">
```

It's not even going on my function.

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger? What does it say?

Comment: It's saying nothing :'( they're is nothing.

Comment: Then either you haven't provided the complete code for the function or you can't debug.

Comment: In the code you provided, you never close your function, just the `if` statement

Comment: Sorry my bad @thanksd i actually do it on my code

Comment: @nicael it's really the full code for my swipe event, but maybe i need to do more :s.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#myImageFront").on("swiperight", function(event) {
    console.log("Hey");
    //do more stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm actually doing this @Johnny Clara

<script>
                $(function(){
                    $( "#myImageFront" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler() );
                    function swipeHandler( event ){
                        $(event.target).swipe;
                    }
                });
            </script>

but i don't know what to add to swipe my image to have the other image.

Comment: @Kira What does "$(event.target).swipe;" supposed to do? Besides, you have an extra open-close parenthesis. You should write: .on("swipe", swipeHandler);

Comment: Actually i'm trying to do the same thing that when you go on amazon website with your mobile you can swipe le images with your finger. and i'm following this tutorial : https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

so the swipeHandler is actually my second function that will do the swipe, but i don't know how to do it but i think the line $(event.target).SOMETHING will do the effect.